# Find the instantaneous velocity

Tags: calculus

At a time $t$ seconds after it is thrown up in the air, a tomato is at a height of $f(t) = −4.9t^2 + 25t + 9$ meters.

Find the instantaneous velocity of the tomato at $t = 1.8$.

Comment: $v=\frac{d}{dt}s$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: You want to calculate the derivative of $f(t)$ and then evaluate the derivative at $t=1.8$, i.e. you want to find $f'(1.8)$.

Answer (score 0):

Speed of the tomato is just $f'$.
$$
f'(t) = -9.8t + 25
$$
Now we can get the speed at $t = 1.8$:
$$
f'(1.8) = -9.8 \cdot 1.8 + 25 = 7.36
$$

Comment: Wait... can one throw a tomato up in the air at 25 m/s?